# Override click event listener of a widget - Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Is there any way that we can override the click event listener of an element of Widget in Titanium?

I have a widget and in a controller where I am using that widget, I need to perform some other action on click of the element than it is defined in the widget.

Is there any way to make it happen?

TIA :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override a given function i would export a setter function in the widget:

Build the Widget as you would always do
**widget.xml:**

```
<Alloy>
    <Button onClick="doClick" title="Hello World!" />
</Alloy>
```

Export a setter function `$.overrideListener` to be able to override `clickHandler` from the outside of the widget
**widget.js:**

```
function doDefaultStuff(e){
    //Do default stuff
}
var clickHandler = doDefaultStuff
function doClick(e){
    clickHandler(e)
}
$.overrideListener = function(callback){
    clickHandler = callback
}
```

**index.xml:**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
       <Widget id="widget_id" src="com.widget.somewidget"></Widget>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Override the `clickHandler` if you wish to do something different than the default behaviour
**index.js:**

```
function doCustomStuff(e){
    //Do Custom Stuff
}
$.widget_id.overrideListener(doCustomStuff)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ofcourse you can override whatever you want.

Using Alloy, you will access widget by **id** parameter & using Classic model, you will simply use widget variable name.

---

Suppose, you have a widget **com.widget.somewidget** in your XML file as:

***index.xml***

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
       <Widget id="widget_id" src="com.widget.somewidget"></Widget>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

---

***widget.xml***

```
<Alloy>
    <Button id="widget_button" title="Hello World!" />
</Alloy>
```

---

In ***widget.js***, you will now import that element for which you want to override the click event like this:

```
$.exportedButtonId = $.widget_button;
```

---

Finally, you can override button click event like this:

***index.js***

```
var widgetButton = $.widget_id.exportedButtonId;
widgetButton.addEventListener('click', function (e){});
```

This is the very basic example of how you can leverage widgets more flexibly, but implementations are endless and depends on application requirements. So **Good Luck!**

Comment: Thanks, Prashant! :)